# Center grid on a horizontal scroll window

Tags: jquery

I have a carousel grid in a fixed width element and I want the middle item to be centered. I am adding the left scroll position on load but that does not account for the browser window width. How can I calculate the window width and get the middle item to be always centered?

```
$('.grid-wrapper').ready(function() {
  $('.grid-wrapper').animate({
     scrollLeft: $('.checked').offset().left - 750
    }, 1000, function() {
  });
});
```

Here is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/khecker/Ld0wu2s9/8/

Comment: The red one to be centered?

Comment: Correct, the red one in the center regardless of the width of the browser window

Comment: But there are 3 on the left and 3 on the right side.Also they have equal space between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `<main>` tag is always 100%:

```
$('.grid-wrapper').ready(function() {
     var pos = $('.checked').offset().left - (($('.grid-wrapper').width()) / 2) + ($('.checked').width() / 2);
    $('.grid-wrapper').animate({
        scrollLeft: pos
    }, 1000, function() {
    })
});
```

If you want to use the window object to calculate sizes you may use `window.innerWidth` instead.